# SQL JOIN returns no columns for join table when columns specified

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I am trying to join 2 tables, however when I specify what columns to return from the first table, I get no columns (at all) from the join table.  If I select all "*" then the join happens and I get the columns returned from the join table.

```
SELECT E.ItemCode, E.ExtendedDescriptionKey 
FROM CI_Item As E 
LEFT JOIN CI_ExtendedDescription AS B 
ON B.ExtendedDescriptionKey = E.ExtendedDescriptionKey
```

The above, I receive only the two columns from E (ItemCode and ExtendedDescriptionKey)

Now, if I do NOT specify columns from the first table, and instead select all:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CI_Item As E 
LEFT JOIN CI_ExtendedDescription AS B 
ON B.ExtendedDescriptionKey = E.ExtendedDescriptionKey
```

I receive the entire CI_Item table AND the JOIN table.  The only difference being that I selected all columns.

I just don't get why this is happening.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand the problem, how do you expect to get columns if you don't select them?

Comment: Well, you get what you ask for. Not more, not less.

Comment: Put the columns you want in the `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes sense guys.  I thought that the SELECT statement is what made up "E".

Comment: Surely you will get "no columns (at all) from the join table" because you have used a **left** join?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't select any fields from table B then it won't show you any in the `SELECT` statement.

You can `SELECT *` for just one table using it's alias if you like;

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM CI_Item As E 
LEFT JOIN CI_ExtendedDescription AS B 
ON B.ExtendedDescriptionKey = E.ExtendedDescriptionKey
```

This will return all fields but only for table E, you could then specify any fields from table B that you wanted;

```
SELECT 
E.*
,B.Field1
.B.Field2 
FROM CI_Item As E 
LEFT JOIN CI_ExtendedDescription AS B 
ON B.ExtendedDescriptionKey = E.ExtendedDescriptionKey
```

Of course, you will have `NULL` values in your columns from table B if there is no matching data.